# Submit button not working with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

im making a website for this company and they have to go through this to make deliveries, for some reason my submit button won't work, sorry im new.

the code i pasted is in 2 different section, the script is on the top while the div class is on the body section.

Tried searching the web but cant seem to find a solution.

```
</script>
<div class="4u12u$(large)">
<input type="checkbox" id="hygiene" name="hygiene"><label for="hygiene">Hygiene</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="safety" name="safety"><label for="safety">Safety</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="pan" name="pan"><label for="pan">Pan/Wheel Chuck</label>
</div>
```

I want to do something like "Check all of this before proceeding" thingy.

Comment: Read [ask] for future questions. This one will be closed.

Comment: The code you have here doesn't include a submit button.  Which could explain why the submit button "won't work".

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: It also doesn't appear to be wrapped in a `<form>`, which you'd need for a submit button or onSubmit logic to fire.

Comment: Hopefully read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before ask the question, you need introduce the problem and code more clearly. And your code doesn't wrap inside `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the basics, ive chosen to GET the form here as it applies to the url

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" checked="checked">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You can learn about html (and other languages) over at https://www.w3schools.com/ they have some good resources to start from.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<div class="4u12u$(large)">
<form action="your url" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" id="hygiene" name="hygiene" required><label for="hygiene">Hygiene</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="safety" name="safety" required><label for="safety">Safety</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="pan" name="pan" required><label for="pan">Pan/Wheel Chuck</label>
</form>    
</div>
```